# Erasing part of a text file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, text, text-mining

I have a text file in my hard disk which is really big. It has around 8 million json files which are separated by comma and I want to remove the last json ; however, because it is really big I cannot do it via regular editors (Notepad++, Sublime, Visual Studio Code, ...). So, I decided to use Python, but I have no clue how to erase part of an existing file using python. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

P.S: My file has such a structure:

```
json1, json2, json3, ...
when each json looks like {"a":"something", "b":"something", "c":"something"}
```

Comment: You need to explain more when you say **I want to erase part of this file**. How can one suggest anything if one does not understand which part of the file you want to erase.

Comment: What do you mean by JSON "files" separated by commas? Do you mean that this one single text file has a number of JSON objects separated by commas, such as `{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}`?

Comment: @blhsing I just added the structure of the file to my question

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to make the file content valid JSON by enclosing it with `[` and `]` so it becomes a list of dicts, and after removing the last item from the list, you can dump it back into a string and then remove its first and the last characters, which will be `[` and `]`, which your original text file does not want:

```
import json
with open('file.txt', 'r') as r, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as w:
    w.write(json.dumps(json.loads('[%s]' % r.read())[:-1])[1:-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want the last JSON object removed from the file, a much more efficient method would be to identify the first valid JSON object at the end of the file and truncate the file from where that JSON object's preceding comma is positioned.

This can be accomplished by seeking and reading backwards from the end of the file, one relatively small chunk at a time, split the buffer by `{` (since it marks the beginning of a JSON object), and prepend the fragments one at a time to a buffer until the buffer is parsable as a JSON object (this makes the code able to handle nested dict structures), at which point you should find the preceding comma from the preceding fragment and prepend the comma to the buffer, so that finally, you can seek the file to where the buffer starts and truncate the file:

```
import json
chunk_size = 1024
with open('file.txt', 'rb+') as f:
    f.seek(-chunk_size, 2)
    buffer = ''
    while True:
        fragments = f.read(chunk_size).decode().split('{')
        f.seek(-chunk_size * 2, 1)
        i = len(fragments)
        for fragment in fragments[:0:-1]:
            i -= 1
            buffer = '{%s%s' % (fragment, buffer)
            try:
                json.loads(buffer)
                break
            except ValueError:
                pass
        else:
            buffer = fragments[0] + buffer
            continue
        break
    next_fragment = fragments[i - 1]
    # if we don't have a comma in the preceding fragment and it is already the first
    # fragment, we need to read backwards a little more
    if i == 1 and ',' not in fragments[0]:
        f.seek(-2, 1)
        next_fragment = f.read(2).decode() + next_fragment
    buffer = next_fragment[next_fragment.rindex(','):] + buffer
    f.seek(-len(buffer.encode()), 2)
    f.truncate()
```